# Add transparent overlay that intercepts swipe events only, and passes other events through

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have an Android app, implemented with C# using Xamarin, that has a LinearLayout containing several EditTexts and TextViews, plus a GridLayout that contains Buttons.  The app works fine, but I want to add functionality to allow the user to access a different activity and screen by swiping left-to-right (or right-to-left) on the current screen (for example, a help activity/screen).

Is it possible to put a transparent overlay over the top of the app that intercepts swipe gestures only (and act on them by, say, starting another activity), but passes touch/click events through to the child objects?  That is, have the app work as it does now, but if the user swipes then start a new activity with a new layout?

I could implement this functionality by adding a button to the app screen, but I'd rather do it with a swipe gesture.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just have your gesture detector just return false for any of the events that you're not interested in handling?

Comment: That works only if I set OnTouchListener for each of the EditTexts, TextViews and Buttons - I was hoping to have a single overlay.  Maybe that's not possible.